# Save Image from Image picker to firebase Storage in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, future, imagepicker

I am trying to upload image in firebase storage getting the image from image picker plugin by accessing camera. Image is not uploading. I also add I change the firebase rules so only authenticated users can upload the image. Git hub [Repo](https://github.com/shahryar-cmyk/chatApp). I used the image uploading logic defined at the **auth_screen.dart** **Line No 48 to 59**[I commented out for time being]. I also add as i add these line my other firebase fuctions which are running prefectly before. getting the errors.

**auth_screen.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

// import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../widgets/auth/auth_form.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var _isLoading = false;

  void _submitAuthForm(
    String email,
    String password,
    String userName,
    File userImage,
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx,
  ) async {
    dynamic authResult;
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      if (isLogin) {
        authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } else {
        print(email);
        print(userName);
        print(userImage.path);
        authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );

        // final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(
        //   app: FirebaseStorage.instance.app,
        //   storageBucket: 'gs://chatapp-1b780.appspot.com',
        // );

        // final StorageReference ref2 =
        //     storage.ref().child('userimage').child('${authResult.user.id}.jpg');
        // final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref2.putFile(userImage);
        // uploadTask.onComplete
        //     .then((value) => print(value))
        //     .catchError((error) => print(error));
        // print(uploadTask.lastSnapshot.error.toString());

        // ///...
        // final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        //     .ref()
        //     .child('user_image')
        //     .child(authResult.user.id + '.jpg');
        // await ref.putFile(userImage).onComplete;

        ///
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(authResult.user.uid)
            .set({
          'username': userName,
          'email': email,
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      var message = 'An error occured,Please check your credentials';
      if (error.message != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        message = error.message;
      }
      print(message);
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(error.toString()),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: AuthForm(_submitAuthForm, _isLoading),
    );
  }
}
```

image being picked using image picker from **auth/auth_form.dart** to  **user_image_picker.dart** where i added the argument so the image is passed down.
**auth/authform.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import '../pickers/user_image_picker.dart';

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isLoading;
  final void Function(String email, String password, String userName,
      File userImage, bool isLogin, BuildContext ctx) submitFn;
  AuthForm(this.submitFn, this.isLoading);
  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _isLogin = true;

  String _userEmail = '';
  String _userName = '';
  String _userPassword = '';
  File _userImageFile;
  void _pickedImage(File image) {
    _userImageFile = image;
  }

  void _trysubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (_userImageFile == null && !_isLogin) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Please Pick an Image'),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        ),
      );
      return;
    }
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      print(_userEmail);
      print(_userPassword);
      widget.submitFn(_userEmail.trim(), _userPassword.trim(), _userName.trim(),
          _userImageFile, _isLogin, context);
      print(_userEmail);
      print(_userPassword);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    if (!_isLogin)
                      UserImagePicker(
                        imagePickFn: _pickedImage,
                        
                      ),
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('emailAdress'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email address',
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                          return 'Please return a valid email address';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (newValue) {
                        _userEmail = newValue;
                      },
                    ),
                    if (!_isLogin)
                      TextFormField(
                        key: ValueKey('userName'),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                            return 'Please Enter at least 4 characters';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (newValue) {
                          _userName = newValue;
                        },
                      ),
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('password'),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                          return 'Please Enter at least 7 characters';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (newValue) {
                        _userPassword = newValue;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    if (widget.isLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    if (!widget.isLoading)
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: _trysubmit,
                        child: Text((_isLogin) ? 'Login' : 'SignUp'),
                      ),
                    if (!widget.isLoading)
                      FlatButton(
                        textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        child: Text(_isLogin
                            ? 'Create new account'
                            : 'I already have an account'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**user_image_picker.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UserImagePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  UserImagePicker({this.imagePickFn});
  final void Function(File pickedImage) imagePickFn;
  @override
  _UserImagePickerState createState() => _UserImagePickerState();
}

class _UserImagePickerState extends State<UserImagePicker> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
    widget.imagePickFn(_image);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          backgroundImage: _image != null ? FileImage(_image) : null,
        ),
        FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: getImage,
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          label: Text('Add Image'),
          textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code here instead of the link to your Github Repo? Some people will downvote your post if they don't see your code.

Comment: @Uni  i uploaded the file where error occur. or i need to upload all the files of the project

Comment: where is the image being picked using image picker?

Comment: I don't really get what wrong and what I can do to help you. Do you want me to show you how I upload images to firebase storage instead?

Comment: Can you tell me how can image is uploaded to firebase storage for authenticated user only.@Uni

Comment: I also uploaded the code where image is being picked.@Uni

Comment: @Uni also can you show me how you upload images to firebase storage instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue i got because i am returning the ImagePicker() function of the file then gettting the image from camera then passing the file to the Fire Storage bucket.
In **user_image_picker.dart**
I written this
`final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);`
Instead of i have to write this
`final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);`

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked me to show you how to upload images to `Firebase Storage`, I will show you the whole procedure including using the `Image Picker` plugin. This is how you should use Image Picker:

```
class PickMyImage{
static Future<File> getImage() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxHeight: 1500,
      maxWidth: 1500,
    );
    if (image != null) {
      return File(image.path);
    }
    return null;
  }
  }
```

This is how you can get and upload that image to firebase storage:

```
   final File _myImage=await PickMyImage.getImage();
   if(_myImage!=null){
      final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("user/${_auth.currentUser().uid}/i"); //i is the name of the image
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
          firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_myImage);
      StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
      var downloadUrl = await storageSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      if (uploadTask.isComplete) {
        final String url = downloadUrl.toString();
        print(url);
        //You might want to set this as the _auth.currentUser().photourl
      } else {
        //error uploading
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the plugin version of firebase storage and imagePicker.

Comment: Here it is:
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+5 and firebase_storage: ^3.1.6 I think even the latest version would work here.

Comment: yes, latest version worked.. and i resolved the issue..Thanks